# Copying each row to another workbook depending on the value on the first column

Tags: excel, vba, export, row, contacts

I have a workbook where there are customer details in a known order exported from another program. First name in column B, last name in column C and so on. There are about 20 columns with different details and multiple rows with different customers.

I want those details to be exported to two different workbooks.

Let's say there are 3 workbooks:

- **coco** for contacts where details are going to be sent from
- **leads** for sale leads and
- **email** for email contact book

There are already rows in those workbooks so exported stuff should go to the last row.

The columns in those two workbooks are in totally different order. So for example cell B4 should go to C column in leads and to D column in email.

However, I don't want every contact to go to both workbooks, leads and email.
Before every row in coco there is a drop down list where user can choose if she/he wants the details of that row to be moved to leads, email or both.

I started making the code to move columns one by one. In that way it would have been much more simple. However I realized, the user should have a possibility to choose where the row is to be exported, the logic is not so simple to me anymore.

Every row (and every cell in a row) has to be handled one by one. I suppose there should be two nested loops that handle first the row and then the cells inside it.

This below is where I started. I don't know it's usable at all anymore. I've also made some experiments afterwards so it might seem a bit messy but paste it anyway.

```
Public lastrowcoco, lastrowleads, lastrowemail As Long
Public shtcoco As Worksheet
Public shtleads As Worksheet
Public wkbname As String
Public wkbcoco As Workbook
Public wkbleads As Workbook
Public rngcoco As Range
Public rowcoco As Range
Public lc, ll, le, nc, nl, ne As Long

Public Sub CopyCells()


    wkbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbcoco = Workbooks(wkbname)
    With wkbcoco
        activesheet.Name = "Transfer"
    End With

    With wkbcoco
        lastrowcoco = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    End With



    Call Copy("B", "D")

lastrowcoco = Empty
lastrowleads = Empty

End Sub
Sub Copy(c As String, Optional le As String, Optional e As String)

    Set shtcoco = wkbcoco.Sheets("Transfer")

    shtcoco.Range(c & "2:" & c & lastrowcoco).Copy

    Set wkbleads = Workbooks.Open("U:\leads.xls")
    Set shtleads = wkbleads.Sheets("Leads")

    With shtleads
        lastrowleads = .cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
    End With

    shtleads.Range(le & 1 + lastrowleads).PasteSpecial


    'wkbleads.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, Joonas

Comment: ... what is your actual question?

Comment: "However I realized, the user should have a possibility to choose where the row is to be exported" Don't you then need 2 dropdown menus to choose from? One for details to be copied and the other one for destination where the copied contents should be pasted to..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Every row on that table is to be copied but some of them only to one place and some to both.

My question is how to do that looping while I want every row to be handled separately and every cell on every row to be handled also separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dest As Range
Set dee = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter destination cell ref ex sheet1!a1", Type:=8)
```

should do it, good luck

Comment: Thanks for that piece of code. I need to clarify my question a bit. As there are something between 0-20 row of contact details and on every row there are 20 column of details, I would like to do the transfer automatically. I do that transfer every month. 

So as the columns are in the known order on all books, I'd like to have some kind of if statements that rule that last name go to last name in the leads and email book (if user want them to go to both) and so on.

I have tried to search a solution but it's that 'where to copy -drop down' that makes things harder.

Comment: i would be more than happy to work through this with you but i could use a little bit more information, maybe what the structure and rules of this transfer is, its hard for me to visualize whats happening and whats lacking from your code

Comment: Thanks but I actually got something. It's not very optimal code though. I'll copy it here later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is my resolution. I could have been a little more accurate about the problem and my sheets. As I said this is far from optimal because there is some unnecessary repetition. I tried first to use more sub procedures but it didn't work because of some declaration issue. Probably some variables were just declared twice.

But here it is anyway. I deleted some too identifying parts.

```
    Sub Copycat()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim today As Date
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Msg As Variant

    If Range("A1") = "Transfer" Then
        Msg = MsgBox("It looks like the script is already executed." & Chr(10) & "Do you really want to execute it again?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "It will add the new columns as double.", vbYesNo, "")
            If Msg = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End If

    If Not Range("B1") = "FirstName" Then
        Msg = MsgBox("It looks like this sheet is not the right file" & Chr(10) & "Do you really want to execute the script?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Unsaved changes will be lost.", vbYesNo, "")
            If Msg = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End If

    'Add columns
    Range("I:T").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Add/change subjects
    Range("A1") = "Transfer"
    Range("C1") = "Seller"
    Range("E1") = ""
    Range("G1") = ""
    Range("T1") = ""
    'Add validation values
    Range("AO2") = "Product1"
    Range("AO3") = "Product2"


    'Removed

    Range("AQ2") = "Both"
    Range("AQ3") = "Email"
    Range("AQ4") = "Leads"

    'Removed


    Range("AU2") = "Prospect"
    Range("AU3") = "Competitor"
    Range("AU4") = "Partner"
    Range("AU5") = "Yes"



    With ActiveSheet
    rCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
    'rCount = ActiveSheet.Range(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'r = Range("J2:J" & rCount)

    For Each cell In Range("J2:J" & rCount)
        cell = Date
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & rCount)
        cell = "Email"
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("O2:O" & rCount)
        cell = "Prospect"
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("N2:N" & rCount)
        cell = "Glass"
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("C2:C" & rCount)
        cell = "RJ"
    Next


     With ActiveSheet.Range("Q2:Q" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AO$2:$AO$7"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With

     With ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AV$2:$AV$4"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With

     With ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AU$2:$AU$5"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With

     With ActiveSheet.Range("M2:M" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AP$2:$AP$12"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
     With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AQ$2:$AQ$4"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
         With ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AR$2:$AR$7"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
     With ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AS$2:$AS$5"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
         With ActiveSheet.Range("P2:P" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AT$2:$AT$7"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
             With ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AS$2:$AS$5"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With
            With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & rCount).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$AQ$2:$AQ$4"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = False
        End With

        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(500, 300, 105, 25).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "PERSONAL.XLSB!Copycat2"
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Submit"
            .Size = 15
        End With
            Selection.Characters.Text = "Submit"

        Range("F25") = "When all the details are filled in, press the button:"
        Cells(1, 1).Select
    End Sub



    Sub Copycat2()

        Dim lastrowcoco, lastrowleads, lastrowemail As Long
        Dim shtcoco, shtleads, shtemail As Worksheet
        Dim wkbname, shtname As String
        Dim wkbcoco, wkbleads, wkbemail As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "FirstName" Then
        MsgBox ("It looks like the sheet where you are running the script is not " & Chr(10) & "from the right one. Check that you have the right sheet active.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim b, v, i, rCount, rCounte As Integer
    rCount = 0
    rCounte = 0

        wkbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Set wkbcoco = Workbooks(wkbname)
        shtname = ActiveSheet.Name
        Set shtcoco = wkbcoco.Worksheets(shtname)

        Set wkbleads = Workbooks.Open("saleleads file.xls")
        Set shtleads = wkbleads.Sheets("Leads")

        Set wkbemail = Workbooks.Open("G:\email list file.xls")
        Set shtemail = wkbemail.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With shtleads
            lastrowleads = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1
        End With
        With shtcoco
            lastrowcoco = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
        End With
        With shtemail
            lastrowemail = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1
        End With
        For i = 2 To lastrowcoco
            If shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Leads" Then
                t = 1
            ElseIf shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Email" Then
                t = 2
            ElseIf shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Both" Then
                t = 3
            End If

                Select Case t
                    Case Is = 1
                        For b = 1 To 33 Step 1
                            shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Copy
                                    Select Case b
                                        Case Is = 2
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 22).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 4
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 23).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 6
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 8
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 24).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 9
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 25).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 10
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 11
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 12
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 13
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 14
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 15
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 16
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 17

                                            End If
                                        Case Is = 18
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 29).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 19
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 30).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 22
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 31).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 23
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 32).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 24
                                        Case Is = 25
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 33).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 29
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 27).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 28
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 26).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 30
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 20).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 31
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 28).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 32
                                            If shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Value = "M" Then
                                                shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).Value = "Mr."
                                            ElseIf shtemail.Cells(i, b).Value = "F" Then
                                                shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).Value = "Ms."
                                            Else: shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            End If
                                    End Select
                        Next b
                    Case Is = 2
                        For b = 1 To 33 Step 1
                            shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Copy
                                    Select Case b
                                        Case Is = 2
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 3
                                        shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 4
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 6
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 9
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 16).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 10
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 11
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 15).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 13
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 15
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 17
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 30
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 25
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 32
                                            If shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Value = "M" Then
                                                shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).Value = "Mr."
                                            ElseIf shtemail.Cells(i, b).Value = "F" Then
                                                shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).Value = "Ms."
                                            Else: shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            End If
                                    End Select
                        Next b
                    Case Is = 3
                        For b = 1 To 33 Step 1
                            shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Copy
                                    Select Case b
                                        Case Is = 2
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 22).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 3
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 4
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 23).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 6
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 8
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 24).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 9
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 25).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 16).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 10
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 11
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 15).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 12
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 13
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 14
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 15
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 16
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 17
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                                                
                                        Case Is = 18
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 29).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 19
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 30).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 22
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 31).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 23
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 32).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 24
                                        Case Is = 25
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 33).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 29
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 27).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 28
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 26).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 30
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 20).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 31
                                            shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 28).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                        Case Is = 32
                                            If shtcoco.Cells(i, b).Value = "M" Then
                                                shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).Value = "Mr."
                                                shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).Value = "Mr."
                                            ElseIf shtemail.Cells(i, b).Value = "F" Then
                                                shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).Value = "Ms."
                                                shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).Value = "Ms."
                                            Else: shtleads.Cells(lastrowleads + rCount, 21).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                                    shtemail.Cells(lastrowemail + rCounte, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                            End If
                                    End Select
                        Next b
                End Select

        If shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Leads" Then
            rCount = rCount + 1
        ElseIf shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Email" Then
            rCounte = rCounte + 1
        ElseIf shtcoco.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Both" Then
            rCount = rCount + 1
            rCounte = rCounte + 1
        End If
        Next i

    wkbemail.Close SaveChanges:=True
    wkbleads.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox rCount & " rows(s) added to Leads and " & rCounte & " to Email list.", 0, "Transfer complete!"

    End Sub
```

Thanks for help!